# sim800l gsm module response isn't completed

Tags: serial, esp8266, softwareserial, gsm, sim800

I am using the `sim800l gsm module` with `nodemcu esp8266` and comunicating with it using AT+ commands. The module is working correctly but I am trying to use the command `AT+CLCC` to get all the current calls' state but it responds with only the first call information and a part of the second call.

This is the response while there are two active calls

```
15:37:19.156 -> AT+CLCC
15:37:19.156 -> +CLCC: 1,0,1,0,0,"+0123456789",145,"name"
15:37:19.156 -> 
15:37:19.156 -> +CLCC: 2,
```

I think it is the Serial buffer's problem because the size of the serial buffer is 64 bytes and the response is more than that but I don't know how to handle that

I hope someone can help.

EDIT: this is the code i am using

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <cstring>

#include <Arduino.h>

#define simTX D3
#define simRX D4

SoftwareSerial sim800l(simRX, simTX);  //RX, TX

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and Arduino IDE (Serial Monitor)

  sim800l.begin(115200);  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and SIM800L

}

void loop() {

  updateSerial();

}


//Start
// this method takes input from the serial monitor the pass it to sim800l via serial communication
void updateSerial() {
  delay(500);
  while (Serial.available()) {
    sim800l.write(Serial.read());  //Forward what Serial received to Software Serial Port
  }
  while (sim800l.available()) {
    Serial.write(sim800l.read());  //Forward what Software Serial received to Serial Port
  }
}
//End
```

Comment: Could you please share your code? Buffer size shouldn't be an issue depending on how you're fetching the response.

Comment: @NickS. i added it in the question :)

Comment: get rid of delay() ... change `while` to `if` ... see what happens

Comment: @jsotola i removed the delay() and changed the while to if as you mentioned and that was the result 
`22:54:55.552 -> AT+CLCC

22:54:55.552 -> +CLCC: 1,0,0,0,1,"+0123456789",145,"name"
22:54:55.552 -> 
22:54:55.552 -> +CLCC:`

still the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for someone in the future who is having the same issue.

the problem was because of the boadrate 115200 is pretty fast for a software serial implementation so i just changed it to 9600

```
 sim800l.begin(9600);  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and SIM800L
```

good luck from the past :)